# Abort trap: 6 in Python3 while downloading data in CSV files

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to download the data of Nifty 50 companies and store them as CSV on my hard disk. I was using the below mentioned code. It successfully downloaded the data for 32 companies but after that it has started giving error= " python3(820,0x70000950d000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9eba7103b0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6". I am on macbook and using terminal.

```
import csv
import urllib.request as urllib
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import nsepy as nse

def saveNiftySymbols():
    url = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty50list.csv"
# pretend to be a chrome 47 browser on a windows 10 machine
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}
    req = urllib.Request(url, headers = headers)
# open the url 
    x = urllib.urlopen(req)
    sourceCode = x.read().decode('utf-8') 

    cr = csv.DictReader(sourceCode.splitlines())
    l = [row['Symbol'] for row in cr]
    return l

def fetchDataFromNse(l):
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime.today()

    for symbol in l:
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(symbol)):
            df=nse.get_history(symbol,start, end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(symbol))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(symbol))

fetchDataFromNse(saveNiftySymbols())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug related to python installations on mac, check this post, it's a bit old but problem is the same
https://github.com/ludwigschwardt/python-gnureadline/issues/50

Comment: I installed ipython and gnureadline and ran the programme again. It gave the same error and then I did something different, I move the import os from line 4 to line 1 and then again ran the programme and it worked. I don't know what exactly was the problem but thanks for the help.